# How could I modify the default notifications for my google calendar?

Tags: notifications, calendar, google-calendar-api, alert

Google by default fires up a notification only 10 mins before. But I want to add more notifications. Like on 30 mins before. One at the time of the event too. Is this possible?

If you refer to the image below, all we see are the notification method. Not even the default value or place to add more reminders? Or is that something available at the event level and not the calendar level?

[image: image here]

Comment: Do you mean editing this from the API? If that's the case, is there any code you're working on? What research did you do until now? Take a look at [Reminders](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders#reminders).

Comment: Feel free to accept and upvote the answer below if you feel it was useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add more than one notification in one specific event on Google Calendar. To do this, follow these steps below:

1. Go to your Google Calendar.
2. Select the event you wanted to have more than one notifications.
3. Click on **Edit event**(the pencil icon that you can see on the
   upper right of the event selected).
4. Under **Event Details** tab, you can see the **Add Notification**
   button.
5. Click the **Add Notification** button. On the first drop-down menu,
   select the type of notification you want to receive(email or a
   pop-up notification message).
6. To schedule when you want the notification be received/appear,
   indicate the specific number of time in the box(or
   you can click the    up and down arrow as an option), and then
   select the unit of    time(minutes, hours, days or weeks) you
   prefer.
7. If you want to have another notification/s for one specific event, you
   can click the **Add Notification** button again and do
   the same    steps from 4-6.
8. Then click **Save**.